# What is the best way to deliver dynamic content to one index.php file?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dynamic

To elaborate a little, I have been using jQuery (started with 1.7 and now use 2) with AJAX to deliver dynamic content to one page without ever needing to actually reload the page. I swivel menus around and reveal new options, flex and arrange information using .css() & .hide/.show depending on the status of my Ajax request.

Here's my big question starting with a statement. Currently, I deliver new content to a page by making an initial ajax call to deliver what's returned in an include.

So let's say I have something like this:

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

and then I have a php file "./includes/content.php" which has this:

```
<?php echo "Hello, World."; ?>
```

I'd then perform an ajax request and on success, run $('#content').html(data) which would replace the inner contents of my div above with Hello, World.

Is there a better way that I should deliver dynamic content? My php files are far more complex and involve constant connectivity/db queries. A friend of mine was telling me I need to use json but I haven't had the time to research this. Would anyone recommend a good place to go that'd break it down at an entry level? I get the concept of json but I don't have any applicable understanding of how to use it.

Comment: this is a very subjective question, the *"best"* way will vary from programmer to programmer and server to server. It all depends on what your app does, what is available to it, and how much time(money) you're willing to put into it. It will all still revolve around ajax though.

Comment: If your content is static, what you are doing is fine. You are effectively using the separate files as a clean way to delineate content on the page. If the content is dynamic you could do 1 of 2 things. 1. collapse all these calls into a single page that returns the specific content using URL parameters (content.php?page=about) or 2. Tie your content.php into a database and have it pull the dynamic content from there.

Comment: I understand that one might consider my question as "too broad" but I think I was direct enough to get a good answer (which I got).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely research and weigh your serialization options as well as which library or implementation has the least learning curve and best performance for your domain model. I prefer JSON as it is much leaner than XML in many cases, so consider the payload/size of your serialized data as well.

I have developed a few single page web applications and I would not recommend doing this exclusively in jquery. A better and far less cumbersome approach is to use one of many javascript MVC frameworks like [backbonesjs](http://backbonejs.org/), [ember](http://emberjs.com/), or [AngularJs](http://angularjs.org/). My latest app is implemented in AngularJs and I now prefer this over the others. However, you cann't go wrong with researching  a few of the frameworks to see what they offer and giving one a try. Anyhow, in my opinion you will have a much better experience using an existing MVC framework especially once you start developing more complex apps.

Comment: While I can certainly appreciate that, a big fear of mine (with using frameworks) is that there will be a bug that's too complex for me to fix within my deadlines. I am a fulltime programmer and I am all about saving time when writing code. I've purchased numerous products on codecanyon for this exact reason.

I'd rather (and I have no problem with your recommendation) learn from the ground up when it comes to things like this specifically. CSS and it's quirks can be figured out when I have more time. What do you think about this? I just want to understand the underlying mechanics first.

Comment: If you have not budgeted time in your project schedule to account for the learning curve of a new framework, then i recommend you use the approach you feel most comfortable with to meet your deadline. Your client could care less about how awesome the framework is when you cannot deliver on time. Learn JSON. Should take a an hour or two tops, but still research JS MVC frameworks in your spare time. You may be able to leverage one for your next project or when you refactor this one. If you need a good baseline for css, use twitter bootstrap3. You will save a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you Athens. Your advice is very much appreciated. I'll take that into considering and I have just started using bootstrap as-of a week ago to avoid css drama. I appreciate it and I have marked it as an answer. I would +1 you but I don't have enough points yet to do that.

Comment: You're Welcome! Also, get an account at http://www.pluralsight.com and watch the Javacript videos related to your concern. They have a free trial and there are plenty of great videos that reduce the learning curve. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

JSON are javascript objects which makes it much easier for JS to parse and take advantage in terms of speeding things up. If you have prior experience with XML.. JSON is nothing different. Its a way you would deliver a data/feed/content to a web page.

If this is your first time looking into JSON. Try http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: I am not fixated on JSON alone. I just want to know what the most commonly used method for content delivery is when using IIS7 (which I should have mentioned), PHP & Jquery.